# Keeping Directline conversations alive for longer than 14 days

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, direct-line-botframework

We are currently developing a platform with the .Net Botframework V4 and Directline on which it is imperative that conversations are accessible over 14 days, which apparently is the limit for directline, when there are no more activities exchanged.

We tried to force directline to create conversations with a predefined conversation id, which didn't work.

There are now two other possibilities, either save the conversation and its state under the new conversation id, and continue as if nothing happened or create a function which periodically sends activities to the conversation, just to keep it alive in directline.

Does anybody have a better solution for this?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an official way as this 14 days limit is by design. Perhaps persisting the conversation in a database might be another approach.

Comment: @RamFattah The conversation is already persisted within a Cosmos DB
We can identify which conversation should be shown to the user, but can't establish the connection once Directline flushed the conversation ID as it then says that the conversation doesn't exist anymore